# R code using loops

Tags: r, loops

Does anyone know how to 1) get the harmonic mean of 3,5,7,9,11 and 2) get the max of 132,152,237,146 using R code loops (for()function)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved without using loop.  `max()` and `mean()` function can be used as follows:

```
nums <- c(132, 152, 237, 146)  
max(nums) # for max
nums2 <- c(3,5,7,9,11)
1/mean(1/nums2) # for harmonic mean
```

Comment: Also for-loops are a very unnatural way to solve a lot of these problems.

Comment: Yes, but I need to know how without loops!

Comment: you can see the answer i have posted does not use any loop. The fuctions `max()` and `mean()` operate on vectors `nums` and `nums2`, and the details of looping over the elements are hidden under the `max` and `mean`  functions implementation.